# Python: how to keep only specific values in a pandas column?

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` like the following

```
df: 
    zip-code
0    00234
1    23450
2    23450
3    10786
4      0
5    xyzvd
```

where `type(df['zip-code']) = str`. I would like to keep only the `5-digit` values and remove all the rest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `str.match` with regex:

```
df[df['zip-code'].str.match("^\d{5}$")]

#zip-code
#0  00234
#1  23450
#2  23450
#3  10786
```

Answer (score 2):

```
z = df['zip-code']
df[z.str.len().eq(5) & z.str.isdigit()]

  zip-code
0    00234
1    23450
2    23450
3    10786
```

Comment: yes but I would like to remove also entries like `xyzvd`